# Pausa en C++ no funciona la pausa al ejecutar el.exe

Tags: c++, exe

Al momento de ejecutar el .exe de un programa en c++ no se pausa, es decir se cierra de golpe y no entiendo porque pasa ya que tengo un "getch" y un (pause))

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
//    int ingles;
//    char nivel[10];
//    printf( "\n   QUE NIVEL DE INGLES CREES QUE TIENES?: " );
//    scanf( "%s","&nivel");


    char r1[10];
    char r2[10];
    char r3[10];
    char respuesta1[] = "eaten";
    char respuesta2[] = "clever";
    char respuesta3[] = "pretty";

    int num_correctas = 0;
    int num_incorrectas = 0;

    printf( "\n  Escribe la palabra que falta-i have never.... indian food-" );  
    gets(r1);

    if (strcmp(respuesta1,r1) == 0 )
    {
       printf( "\n  correcto");
       num_correctas = num_correctas + 1;
    }
    else
    {
      printf( "\n  incorrecto");
      num_incorrectas = num_incorrectas + 1; 
    }

       printf( "\n    sinonimo de +intelligent+-" );  
    gets(r2);

    if (strcmp(respuesta2,r2) == 0 )
    {
       printf( "\n  correcto");
       num_correctas = num_correctas + 1;
    }
    else
    {
      printf( "\n  incorrecto");
      num_incorrectas = num_incorrectas + 1; 
    }

    printf( "\n sinonimo de +beautiful+- " );  
    gets(r3);

    if (strcmp(respuesta3,r3) == 0 )
    {
       printf( "\n  correcto");
       num_correctas = num_correctas + 1;
    }
    else
    {
      printf( "\n  incorrecto");
      num_incorrectas = num_incorrectas + 1; 
    }

    printf("\n Numero de respuestas correctas: %d", num_correctas);
    printf("\n Numero de respuestas incorrectas: %d", num_incorrectas);
    return 0;

   ("PAUSE()"); 
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Las sentencias `PAUSE();` y `getch();` deberían ir antes del `return 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error esta en que llamas a `return` antes de hacer la pausa, ya que tu `return` termina el programa, razon por la cual no te hace la pausa.

Otro error es `("PAUSE()");`, codigo que no llama a ninguna funcion, quisa necesites hacer `system("pause")`, el cual imprimira una mensaje: **Presione una tecla para continuar . . .**, en tu consola.

Otra cosa es que utilizas `getch();`, codigo que espera que se precione una tecla para continuar. Se podria decir que es una pausa sin ningun tipo de mensaje.

Asi que al final tu puedes utilizar solo una de las dos opciones [`system("pause")` ó `getch();`].

Tus ultimas lineas de código quedarían de la siguiente manera:

```
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Ten en cuenta que este codigo solo servirá en sistemas operativos windows.

**Ó**

```
getch();
return 0;
```

Caso que se utilizaba en lenguaje `C`.

Asi que en `C++` se tiene una mejor opcion:

```
cin.get();
return 0;
```